# ValueError - Cannot assign

Tags: django

please i have a form and model class like the ones below, but each time i try sending data to the database i get this error:

> ValueError at /activity/add/product/  Cannot assign "u'Cameras'":
>   "user_products.category" must be a "categories" instance.

please is there guru who can help me fix this. Thanks.

## form

```
class headersearch(forms.Form):
    kywords = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, error_messages = {'required': 'Please type a keyword to search'})
    catgory = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(headersearch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['catgory'].choices = header_search()

class advancedsearch(forms.Form):
    kywords = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    catgory = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    priceRangeFrom = forms.IntegerField()
    priceRangeTo = forms.IntegerField()
    state = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=STATE_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(advancedsearch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['catgory'].choices = header_search()

class additem(forms.Form):
    productName = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    category = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices = ADD_CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    priceFrom = forms.IntegerField()
    productState = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length = 200)
    tags = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    image = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, required = False)
    dateAdded = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, initial = datetime.datetime.today)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(additem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].choices = add_product()
```

## model

```
class grp_categorie(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    visibleOnNavi = models.BooleanField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.category)


class categories(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(grp_categorie)
    member = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    values = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.values)


class user_products(models.Model):
    productName = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(categories)
    priceFrom = models.IntegerField()
    productState = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/%Y/%m/%d", blank = True, null = True)
    dateAdded = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s" %(self.productName, self.category, self.priceFrom, self.productState, self.description, self.tags, self.image, self.dateAdded)
```

## here is the view that handles the form

```
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        formadd = additem(request.POST)
        if formadd.is_valid():
            cd = formadd.cleaned_data
            p = user_products(
                productName = cd['productName'],
                category = cd['category'],
                priceFrom = cd['priceFrom'],
                productState = cd['productState'],
                description = cd['description'],
                tags = cd['tags'],
                image = cd['image'],
                dateAdded = cd['dateAdded']
            )

            p.save()
            request.session['product'] = cd['productName']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/activity/add/product/done/')
    else:
        formadd = additem()
    return render_to_response('activity/add_item.html', { "formadd" : formadd }, context_instance = RequestContext(request, processors=[navi]))
```

## here is the snapshop of the error page

[image: error page]

the error comes up each time i submit the form.

## Traceback

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
>   http://localhost:8000/activity/add/product/
>
> Django Version: 1.3.1 Python Version: 2.7.2 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.sites', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.admindocs',  'south', 
>   'mystore.store'] Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "C:\django_sites\www\mystore..\mystore\store\views.py" in add_product
>     81.                 dateAdded = cd['dateAdded'] File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in **init**
>     352.                 setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in
>   **set**
>     331.                                  self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /activity/add/product/ Exception Value:
>   Cannot assign "u'Cameras'": "user_products.category" must be a
>   "categories" instance.

Comment: Even gurus aren't pyschic. Show the *full* traceback, and the part of the code where the error is actually happening (probably your view).

Comment: Sigh. What am I supposed to do with a snapshot of the error page? You see that link that says "Switch to copy-and-paste view'? Click it, copy the text in the box, and post it here.

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing where this error is happening (the code in the traceback) but it's most definitely a problem somewhere you're creating the model from the form.

> ValueError at /activity/add/product/ Cannot assign "u'Cameras'": "user_products.category" must be a "categories" instance.

As it says, when setting `user_products.category`, you must pass it a `categories` instance, not a string `Cameras`

```
user_products = user_products()
user_products.category = 'Cameras' # will cause ValueError on FK field
```

If you're working with form POST data, you'll have to pull the related object from the string "Camera". It should be something more like...

```
user_products.category = categories.objects.get(grp_categorie__category='Camera')
# replace with a method to actually get your categories instance.
```